# how to configure different landing page for abp.io

Tags: abp

i am new in using abp.io . i am looking for a way to point as startup page. As per default it is using login page as startup page. I want it to point to a new landing page as startup page.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean just a page inside your application, it depends if your application is just an api or MVC or a Razor Page application. But generally, redirecting to "*LandingPage*" from your *Home* Page/Controller action works.

If you mean an admin (back-office application) and a public application, you need to create a new application and register it as a client to identityserver.

You can check the [microservice-demo sample](https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/tree/master/MicroserviceDemo/applications) that while **BackendAdminApp.Host** is an admin application, *PublicWebSite.Host* is a public application.

Comment: My app is Razor Page. I want to point the landing page to my own landing page.I have added in startup.cs in fuction ConfigureServices() this line services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>  {  options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Portal/Index", "");});
but i'm getting this error "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:/Portal/Index/Index"